# How to query with filter of column values and get last values of raw?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Here I get the last value of pushkey(column) by below code

```
String abc="value for filtering data"
    String selectQuery= "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME+" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
            SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            String str = "";
            if(cursor.moveToFirst())
                str  =  cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PUSH_KEY) );
            Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            cursor.close();
```

***But now I want to get last value of pushkey when fromid(column) set filter by some predefined String abc value. So how to add filter and make query ?***

https://i.stack.imgur.com/77thU.png

Comment: Add a WHERE clause maybe?

Comment: @forpas : i am not familiar to write query , if you dont mind please add an answer with full query

Comment: Why don't you post sample data and expected results preferably in text mode? The query in the code does not even use the same column names. What do you mean by: *last values of push key...*?

Comment: last values of push key...?  : pushkey is column and get last values pushkey column WHEN fromid set filter  "DIX....UVa2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by last you mean ordered by ID descending then add a WHERE clause like this:

```
String selectQuery= "SELECT pushkey FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE fromid  = 'DIX....UVa2' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"
```

If you just want to filter by fromid:

```
String selectQuery= "SELECT pushkey FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE fromid  = 'DIX....UVa2'"
```

If you want all the columns, change to:

```
String selectQuery= "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE fromid  = 'DIX....UVa2'"
```

Use this Java code:

```
String fromid = "DIX....UVa2";
String selectQuery= "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE fromid  = ?";
SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, fromid);
String str = "";
if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    str  =  cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PUSH_KEY) );
Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
cursor.close();
```

Replace `"DIX....UVa2"` with the value that you want to filter the column `fromid`.

This will toast the 1st value of the results.

Comment: What do you mean by last values? All the values?

Comment: its a mistake "values" and if i have predefined string instead of DIX....UVa2, than how do i write means as "String" or 'String' or String ?

Comment: in first case :
you say clause 
" WHERE fromid  = 'DIX....UVa2'

i need to replace 'DIX....UVa2' with other predefined string also

Comment: Yes, so what do you mean?

Comment: if i have String abc="value" than how do i write it as "abc" or 'abc' or abc in 
" WHERE fromid = 'DIX....UVa2' ?

Comment: Use the Java code at the end of my answer. Replace `String fromid = "DIX....UVa2";` with `String fromid = "abc";`. This 'abc' will trplace the ? in the query. This is how it's done in Java.

Comment: trying hard but not understand exactly

Comment: This is how you use rawQuery() when you want to filter a table: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String%5B%5D)

Comment: please see my question

Comment: @tailor Please _don't_ keep editing your question when you got an answer. Doing so will invalidate the answer. Post a new question instead.

Comment: Where is the id in your data? Again you say last values. How many values? Or do you mean only 1 value?

Comment: which id you are talking about ?

Comment: its a column name please see image link